# Flexbox : not being able to use space-between on a container items

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

Hello guys I'm having issue with my lil' page im working on :

(there's a codesandbox for this code, assuming it's more comfortable
https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-shockley-m753n also added a picture so you'll have an idea of what i'm aiming for)

what i'm trying to do is to create a space between the items inside the sidebar-containers block.

Layout :

```
.container {
    max-width: 100rem;
    margin: 8rem auto;

    box-shadow: var(--shadow-dark);
    min-height: 90rem; //page lenght

}

.sidebar {
    flex: 0 0 20%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: rgba(219, 219, 219, 0.685);
    
}

.content {
    display: flex;
}

.cv-view{
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 90rem;
    flex:1 ;
}
```

base:

```
:root {
    --color-primary: #eb2f64;
    --color-primary-light: #FF3366;
    --color-primary-dark: #BA265D;

    --color-grey-light-1: #faf9f9;
    --color-grey-light-2: #f4f2f2;
    --color-grey-light-3: #f0eeee;
    --color-grey-light-4: #ccc;
    
    --color-grey-dark-1: #333;
    --color-grey-dark-2: #777;
    --color-grey-dark-3: #999;

    --shadow-dark: 0 2rem 6rem rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    --shadow-light: 0 2rem 5rem rgba(0,0,0,.06);

    --line: 1px solid var(--color-grey-light-2);
}

* {
    margin :0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}


html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 62.5%; // 1rem = 10px, 10px/16px = 62.5%
}

body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.6;
    color: var(--color-grey-dark-2);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

components :

```
**.sidebar-containers {
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-top: 50px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    &__item{
        display:flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        border-bottom: solid 1px ;
        padding: 5px;
        list-style: none;
        &__title {
            font-weight: 400;
            font-size: 2.5rem;
            
        }
    }
    
}**
```

Index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon.png">
    </head>
    <body>
       <div class="container">
           <div class="content">
                    <div class="sidebar">
                        <div class="sidebar-containers">
                            <ul class="sidebar-containers__item">
                                <h1 class="sidebar-containers__item__title">Contact :</h1>
                                <li>Email : help@meplz.com</li>
                                <li>Phone : 555-5555</li>
                                <li>Address: Cluelessland</li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul class="sidebar-containers__item">
                                <h1 class="sidebar-containers__item__title">Education:</h1>
                                <li>Udemy</li>
                                <li>Udemy</li>
                            </ul>
                            
                            <ul class="sidebar-containers__item">
                                <h1 class="sidebar-containers__item__title">Skills:</h1>
                                <li>Helpmestackover</li>
                                <li>Asking questions</li>
                                <li>Please</li>
                            </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <main class="cv-view">
                CV View
            </main>
           </div>
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

thanks in advance for any kind of help!

Comment: how much space and where is the picture. I can't find the link

Comment: the picture is inside the example folder in the link to the codesandbox

Answer (score 0):

You neeed to set a `height` for `.sidebar`, otherwise it will just be as high as its contents require, causing `space-between` not to have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `height` to `.sidebar-containers` class according to your need e.g,

```
height:100%;
```

Or

```
height:100vh;
```

Or you can also give height in pixels, rems etc.